# Scanner input == null?

Tags: java, if-statement, null

I am trying to say if you enter a character it will do this; else if scanner input == null do this instead. I'm not getting any syntax errors, I just need to know how to word this so that if you don't enter any characters and hit ENTER then it will go to my default settings. 
Here is what I have so far.

```
Shape sq = new Square(10);
                System.out.println("Choose character to fill your shape. A-Z, a-z, ! # $ % & ( ) * + Press ENTER.");
                characterChoiceSquare = input.next();
                if(characterChoiceSquare == input.next())
                {
                    for(int m = 0; m < shapeChars.length; m++)
                    }
                    {
                        if(characterChoiceSquare.equals(shapeChars[m]));
                        {
                            char[] c1 = characterChoiceSquare.toCharArray();
                            char[] shapeCharacter = new char[sq.getSizeInt()];
                            for(int i = 0; i < sq.getSizeInt(); i++) 
                            {
                                shapeCharacter[i] = c1[0]; // repeat the char input to fit shapeString
                            }
                            string = String.valueOf(shapeCharacter); //assign the value of the arraylist to shapeString

                            shapeString += string + "\n";

                            System.out.print(shapeString);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(characterChoiceSquare == null)
                {
                    System.out.print(sq.displayCharacters());
                }
```

Comment: you can use .isEmpty() as your condition for when the use does not enter anything instead just hits enter.

Comment: My if - else statement wasn't being used in my code. That does give me errors. So far, without the if-else idea, it prints both options. Maybe if-else isn't the way. but the idea is either pick a character or go to default which is random chars making the same shape

Comment: you mean if(scanner.isEmpty()) ??

Comment: then you can use switch case as @Jonah Haney has already suggested.

Comment: is that a built-in for scanner or would I have to create a new method?

Comment: ok thanks. I'll work on it =)

Comment: in your case  it would be like characterChoiceSquare.isEmpty()

Comment: I've added this:       if(String.valueOf(c1).isEmpty())
       {
        System.out.print(sq.displayCharacters());
       }
       else
       {
        System.out.print(shapeString);
       }

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `input.nextLine()`, then your check would be

```
else if (String.valueOf(characterChoiceSquare).equals("")){
    ...
}
```

Or, alternatively, don't even do an `else-if` check, just have a final `else` statement that would result if no other `if` statement returns true.

Another way of doing this would be using `switch-case` as I would recommend:

```
switch (String.valueOf(characterChoiceSquare)){
    case "a":
        //do stuff
        break;
    case "b":
        //do stuff
        break;
    case "":
        //do stuff if characterChoiceSquare is empty
        break;
    default:
        //Do this if characterChoiceSquare does not match any cases
}
```

Comment: wouldn't (characterChoiceSquare.isEmpty()) as a string be the same as (characterChoiceChoiceSquare.toString().isEmpty()) as a char or even (String.valueOf(characterChoiceSquare).isEmpty))

Comment: @StephS Oh is `characterChoiceSquare` a `Character` or a `String`?

Comment: @ Jonah - It is a char

Comment: @StephS I have updated my answer to reflect that. And as for your original question, no it is not. `characterChoiceSquare.isEmpty()` does not exist. However the other options are correct.

Comment: Ok well I tried isEmpty and they are not working. They simply do nothing as I have them.

Comment: if(String.valueOf(characterChoiceSquare).isEmpty())
     {
      System.out.print(sq.displayCharacters());
     }   
     else
     {
       System.out.print(shapeString);
     }